# не работает pyuic или другие способы конвертации из ui в py

Tags: python, pyqt5, ui

Всем привет. Установил Qt Creator, сделал формочку, теперь имеется проект, в котором, как я понимаю нужно как-то из ui формата сделать py. Пробовал через pyuic, но не вариант так как он элементарно не устанавливается через pip.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сперва подумал что у меня pip неправильно работает, но с pip, вроде все нормально [image]

Есть ли другие способы конвертации ui в py, или может кто знает как исправить эту ошибку? Работаю на mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pyuic5` является частью библиотеки `PyQt`. Соответственно, если у вас установлена `PyQt`, то `pyuic5` должен быть тоже.

Для установки `pyqt`:

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Установщик по-умолчанию создает `entry_points` скрипт в директории исполняемых файлов `python`, которая указана в `PATH`.

Для проверки:

```
which pyuic5
```

Если скрипт найден, то можно запускать:

```
pyuic5 -x foo.ui -o foo.py
```

Comment: спасибо помогло, правда почему-то без sudo в начале команды - было очень много ошибок. В Pycharm можно как-то прикрутить, чтобы не вылезая из проекта все конвертировалось и работало норм?

Comment: Видимо, у вас `python` установлен в `usr` - каталог, поэтому `sudo` требуется для получения прав на запись установщику. Насчет шарма не знаю, лучше задать это отдельным вопросом.